# Object Security in Parse using the JavaScript API - Tying Users to the objects that are saved

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, marionette, parse-platform

In managing entities in Parse there are a lot of objects that I need to tie to the current logged in user.

My concerns are:

2. There is no backend code ensuring that the `User` being passed in is the current logged in user.
3. Users could assign any newly created objects to other users.

They have [this example TODO app](http://parseplatform.github.com/Todo/) which in [the documentation](https://parse.com/tutorials/todo-app-with-javascript) shows no Cloud Code in place to ensure that the `User` that the `Todo` is assigned to is the currently logged in user.

Now that I look through [the code](http://parseplatform.github.com/Todo/js/todos.js) I'm starting to think that whenever an object is saved it gets tied to the user. Can anyone explain why this application works and how it is associating the `Todo`s with the `User`?

**UPDATE:** Nevermind, I found the place in their code where they specify the user to save for the Todo. My question is, what's stopping a user from writing code that saves the todo with someone else's user id?

```
this.todos.create({
        content: this.input.val(),
        order:   this.todos.nextOrder(),
        done:    false,
        user:    Parse.User.current(),
        ACL:     new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current())
      });
```

**UPDATE #2:** If the `User` object has an `ACL` set to only allows users to be able to read `User` objects they own, then they wouldn't be able to query to get another user object to pass up. However, there are two other possible problems:

1. Is it possible for them to pass the objectId of the user instead of the entire `User` object even if the `user` field on the `Todo`s table requires a `_User`?
2. I believe they could also create a new user object and assign it to that... I'm trying to think of a scenario where this would be an issue, but I can't right now.

If anyone can confirm or provide solutions to either of those that would be helpful. Going to try to test #1 right now.

**UPDATE #3 -- After some testing:**

1. If the `user` field on the `Todo`s table requires a `_User` object, it will not take the objectId as a string.
2. The they can however create a new user object and set the objectId there to get around this.

   ```
   var user = new Parse.User();      // Create user object
   user.id = "cqmEuj1Bzf";           // Assign user id

   // Create and save Todo
   var td = new Todo();              
   td.set("name", "Some ting todo");
   td.set("user", user);
   td.save();
   ```

This right here is exactly what I was worried about. **I was able to successfully save a Todo to another user's account**--as long as I know their user_id (`objectId`). With enough users they can likely guess at least one to randomly screw up someone's account.

So what now?

**Answer:** Use Cloud Code to verify that the user passed in matches the current user. Answer was posted on [Parse's forums here](https://parse.com/questions/object-security-in-parse-using-the-javascript-api-tying-users-to-the-objects-that-are-saved).

Comment: Hey I split your find into its own answer to make it easier to find SO style.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cloud code to verify that the user passed in matches the current user. That answer was posted on [Parse's forums here](https://parse.com/questions/object-security-in-parse-using-the-javascript-api-tying-users-to-the-objects-that-are-saved).

> You can use Cloud Code to ensure that the objectId corresponds to the
>   current user making this request. In fact, our sample application,
>   Anypic, does this check on the "Photo" and "Activity" class.
>
> From Anypic's Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Activity', function(request, response) {   var currentUser = Parse.User.current();    var objectUser = request.object.get('fromUser');

  if(!currentUser || !objectUser) {
    response.error('An Activity should have a valid fromUser.');   } else if (currentUser.id === objectUser.id) {
    response.success();   } else {
    response.error('Cannot set fromUser on Activity to a user other than the current user.');   } });

Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Photo', function(request, response) {   var currentUser = Parse.User.current();    var objectUser = request.object.get('user');

  if(!currentUser || !objectUser) {
    response.error('A Photo should have a valid user.');   } else if (currentUser.id === objectUser.id) {
    response.success();   } else {
    response.error('Cannot set user on Photo to a user other than the current user.');   } });
```